# Matplotlib & Pandas DateTime Compatibility

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

**Problem**: I am trying to make a very simple bar chart in Matplotlib of a Pandas DataFrame. The DateTime index is causing confusion, however: Matplotlib does not appear to understand the Pandas DateTime, and is labeling the years incorrectly. How can I fix this?

**Code**

```
# Make date time series
index_dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2021-01-01')

# Make data frame with some random data, using the date time index
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index_dates,
                  data = np.random.rand(len(index_dates)), 
                  columns=['Data'])

# Make a bar chart in marplot lib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

df.plot.bar(ax=ax)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
```

Instead of showing up as 2018-2021, however, the years show up as 1970 - 1973.
[image]

I've already looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902371/matplotlib-bar-chart-with-dates), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517171/matplotlib-pandas-datetime-frequency), and documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html). I know the date timeindex is in fact a datetime index because when I call `df.info()` it shows it as a datetime index, and when I call `index_dates[0].year` it returns 2018. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: df.plot.bar only plots against range index and rename the tick labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with mixing `df.plot.bar` and `matplotlib` here.

`df.plot.bar` sets tick locations starting from 0 (and assigns labels), while `matplotlib.dates` expects the locations to be the number of days since 1970-01-01 (more info [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html)).

If you do it with `matplotlib` directly, it shows labels correctly:

```
# Make a bar chart in marplot lib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

plt.bar(x=df.index, height=df['Data'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
```

Output:

[image: chart]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this worked great! Changed from plt.bar() to ax.bar() to keep track of axis object more carefully.